# Struts2 save locale in a cookie

Tags: struts2

I wish to save request locale in browser cookie so that the next time a new user session is created
this 'locale' cookie is read and specific page is displayed.
Need a way to do this in struts2

Comment: you can set cookies as usual way and later on can use cookies interceptor to read cookies

Answer (score 0):

Struts dosn't have this as build in function.

First you need to save a cookie with JavaScript

```
document.cookie = "locale_cookie=fa_IR";
```

Second extend the `I18nInterceptor` and change `getLocaleFromParam`. You can  add reading from cookie feature hear (you can extend other methods too):

The method should be some think like below:

```
@Override
getLocaleFromParam () {

  //read cookie and find cookie which its name is locale_cookie
  Cookie[] cookies = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getCookies();

  for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
       if( "locale_cookie".equals(cookie.getName()){
          return LocalizedTextUtil.localeFromString( cookie.getName());
        }       
   }
  ..............
  //The rest method
}
```